# Python: apply function across categories and save results to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to Python. I am analyzing EEG data. I have created the function `extract_bands` to calculate the values of the **EEG bands** (based on [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/45662)) but I am having trouble applying the function across categories and saving the aggregated data in a new dataset

This is a simplified dataset, `pddf`:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  


simple_df = {'subject': ['s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s3','s3','s3','s3','s3','s3','s4','s4','s4','s4','s4','s4'],
        'group': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c'], 
        'trial': ['1','1','2','2','4','4','2','2','3','3','5','5','1','1','2','2','3','3','3','3','5','5','6','6'],
                'cond': ['c1','c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c1','c1','c2','c2','c2','c2','c2','c2','c1','c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c1','c1','c2','c2'],
             'value': [ 8.88260935, 82.97797122, 18.26659492,  7.70070742, 12.76417463,
       68.35936355,  7.59613253, 54.36616722,  9.11860667, 24.20324845,
       86.1674253 , 99.96479613, 40.83798898, 23.72822971, 49.77969641,
        2.19459866, 30.3883309 , 46.75944945, 11.47003917, 26.71771771,
       88.93251086,  7.29166478,  7.76880683, 40.65701944]
        }

pddf = pd.DataFrame(simple_df, columns = ['subject', 'group', 'trial', 'cond', 'value'])
```

Here is the function `extract_bands`:

```py
# define frequency
fs = 256 

# define EEG bands
eeg_bands = {'Delta': (0, 4),
             'Theta': (4, 8),
             'Alpha': (8, 12),
             'Beta': (12, 30),
             'Gamma': (30, 45)}

def extract_bands (data):
    fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(data))
    fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(data), 1.0/fs)
    eeg_band_fft = dict()
    for band in eeg_bands:  
        freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= eeg_bands[band][0]) & 
                       (fft_freq <= eeg_bands[band][1]))[0]
        eeg_band_fft[band] = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])
    return eeg_band_fft
```

I can apply the function to one trial and I obtain the values of the EEG bands saved in a dictionary, `eeg_band_fft`.
In the real dataset, each trial has 256 samples; here one trial has only 2 samples, so the function returns the value for the `Delta` band only.

```py
one_trial = pddf[(pddf.subject == "s1") & (pddf.cond == 'c1') & (pddf.trial == '1')]

print(one_trial)
#>   subject group trial cond      value
#> 0      s1     a     1   c1   8.882609
#> 1      s1     a     1   c1  82.977971

extract_bands(one_trial.value)

#> {'Delta': 91.86058057, 'Theta': nan, 'Alpha': nan, 'Beta': nan, 'Gamma': nan}
```

**Question**

Now, how can I apply the function `extract_bands` across trials belonging to the same condition `cond`, for each `subject`?

Basically I would like to return a dataset with a row for each `cond` per `subject`, and a total of eight columns : 'subject', 'group', 'cond' and the values for the five EEG bands from the dictionary `eeg_band_fft`.

**Example**

The following code does what I want (for calculating avarages) using `groupby`, but I don't know how to make it work using the function `extract_bands`.

```py
pddf2 = pddf.groupby(["subject", "group", "cond"]).value.mean() # take the mean
pddf2
#> subject  group  cond
s1       a      c1      29.456971
                c2      40.561769
s2       a      c1      30.981150
                c2      54.863519
s3       c      c1      32.280519
                c2      32.283109
s4       c      c1      48.112088
                c2      21.653396
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform a custom aggregation on your DataFrame, you should use the function `agg` and specify your custom function. Then you should transform the dict column into a DataFrame, and finally concatenate the two DataFrames.

I would do as follows:

```
dfg = (pddf.groupby(["subject", "group", "cond"])
        .agg({'value' : lambda x: extract_bands(x)})
        .reset_index()
)
df_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dfg['value'])
result = pd.concat([dfg.drop(columns=['value']), df_dict], axis=1)
```

This code returns the following DataFrame:

```
subject group cond       Delta  Theta  Alpha  Beta  Gamma
0      s1     a   c1  117.827883    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
1      s1     a   c2   81.123538    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
2      s2     a   c1   61.962300    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
3      s2     a   c2  219.454077    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
4      s3     c   c1  129.122075    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
5      s3     c   c2   64.566219    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
6      s4     c   c1   96.224176    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
7      s4     c   c2   86.613583    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
```